# How display 2 model tables on 1 admin page

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a general error model and "child models" I want to display all the tables of child models on the error page.
Example:

```
#models.py

class Errors(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Errors"

class Error1(models.Model):
    error1 = models.TextField(('Error1'), blank=True, null=True)

class Error2(models.Model):
    error2 = models.TextField(('Error2'), blank=True, null=True)

class Error3(models.Model):
    error3 = models.TextField(('Error3'), blank=True, null=True)

#admin.py

@admin.register(Errors)
class ErrorsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/errors/errors.html'
    ...
```

Comment: Well, they are not actually "child models", they are just models, on their own. Since there are nothing that can relate them to the "general error model". Take a look at [many to one relationships.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Comment: I understand that you can communicate many to one, but this is just the connection of the database. Maybe I was incorrectly expressed. I want to output several logically related models on 1 page. If we abstract from my code and take the standard Django has standard users and groups. I want to make a page / model which would reflect all records form users & groups in the form of a table. I can make custom html with tables, but I would like to see on the page django tables with operating functionality like: action (delete, select ... )